# Python regex evading optional non capturing group when there's nothing else to match in the second group

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to clean a file which have some uoms written with item names without any space in between. I came up with a regex to match the uom and their variations which works fine on their own but when grouped to capture the item names, it fails to give the expected output.

```
import re

uom_regex = 'box(?:es)?|bxs|bag(?:s)?'
test_text = ["box", "boxes", "bag", "bags", "bxs"]

for text in test_text:
    match = re.search(uom_regex, text)
    print(match.group() if match else "No match")
```

This regex, on its own, works fine and captures all uoms perfectly.

But when I am trying the same regex in conjunction with other parts to add space where they are due, it works fine except for when the word does not really have any extras (like in the case first 2 cases of the example below

```
import re

uom_regex = 'box(?:es)?|bxs|bag(?:s)?'
regex = r'({0})([a-zA-Z]+)'.format(uom_regex)

test_strings = ["boxes", "bags", "boxesapple", "boxapple", "bagapple", 'bagsapple']

for test_string in test_strings:
    result = re.sub(regex, r'\1 \2', test_string)
    print(f"Original: {test_string}")
    print(f"Modified: {result}\n")
```

Here's the output.

```
Original: boxes
Modified: box es

Original: bags
Modified: bag s

Original: boxesapple
Modified: boxes apple

Original: boxapple
Modified: box apple

Original: bagapple
Modified: bag apple

Original: bagsapple
Modified: bags apple
```

Whereas, the first 2 outputs should have been like this.

```
Original: boxes
Modified: boxes

Original: bags
Modified: bags
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the wanted output for each exam key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
(?=(box(?:es)?|bxs|bags?))\1([a-zA-Z]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mz4WRN/1).

**NOTE**: If you are using Python 3.11 and newer where the `re` module supports possessive quantifiers/atomic groups, you may use `(box(?:es)?+|bxs|bags?+)([a-zA-Z]+)` with the original replacement pattern in `re.sub`.

*Details*:

- `(?=(box(?:es)?|bxs|bags?))` - a positive lookahead that captures into Group 1 either `box`, `boxes`, `bxs`, `bag` or `bags`
- `\1` - same text as captured in Group 1
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - Group 2: any one or more ASCII letters.

Here is how you can use it in your code:

```py
import re
 
uom_regex = 'box(?:es)?|bxs|bags?'
regex = r'(?=({0}))\1([a-zA-Z]+)'.format(uom_regex)
 
test_strings = ["boxes", "bags", "boxesapple", "boxapple", "bagapple", 'bagsapple']
 
for test_string in test_strings:
    result = re.sub(regex, r'\1 \2', test_string)
    print(f"Original: {test_string}")
    print(f"Modified: {result}\n")
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/X6xE2r)

Output:

```
Original: boxes
Modified: boxes

Original: bags
Modified: bags

Original: boxesapple
Modified: boxes apple

Original: boxapple
Modified: box apple

Original: bagapple
Modified: bag apple

Original: bagsapple
Modified: bags apple
```

Answer (score 0):

If one uses Python's [PyPI regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (similar to PCRE), matches of the following regular expression can be replaced with a space.

```
\b(?:box(?:(?!es)|es)|bag(?:(?!s)|s)|bxs)\K(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p3Jtst/1)

This expression has the following elements.

```
\b           # match a word boundary
(?:          # begin (outer) non-capture group
  box        # match literal
  (?:        # begin non-capture group
    (?!es)   # negative lookahead asserts next two chars are not 'es'
  |          # or
    es       # match literal
  )          # end non-capture group
|            # or
  bag        # match literal
  (?:        # begin non-capture group
    (?!s)    # negative lookahead asserts next char is not 's'
  |          # or
    s        # match literal
  )          # end non-capture group
|            # or
  bxs        # match literal
)            # end (outer) non-capture group
\K           # reset start of match and discard previously-consumed chars
(?=[a-zA-Z]) # positive lookahead asserts next char is a letter
```